# Xamarin WebView Audio.Play is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, audio, webview

I am displaying an offline local file page in my WebView.

In that web page I have a script that contains the following snippet:

```
var BUTTON_CLICK_SOUND = "UklGRkgDAABXQVZFZm10IB-trimmed-for-stackoverflow";

buttonClickSound = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + BUTTON_CLICK_SOUND);

buttonClickSound.play();
```

It is throwing the exception:

```
interface.js:525 Uncaught TypeError: buttonClickSound.play is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (interface.js:525)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

I looked at it through google chrome remote dev tool and the play function is indeed missing from the audio object I just created.

It was working just fine when I ran that snippet from a remote website.

This is how I set up my WebView:

```
  global::Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

  mainBrowser = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.mainBrowser);
  mainBrowser.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
  mainBrowser.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
  mainBrowser.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
  mainBrowser.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
  mainBrowser.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
```

If I had to guess. It would be that its forcing the `MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` security, but I do not know why if it wasn't an issue when the javascript file was loaded from a website.

Any ideas on what is causing the play function to disappear when trying to play an audio file from a base64 encoded string?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the Audio tag in html in advance and  call `play()` on the audio element.

```
  <audio id="audio" >
   <source src="xxx.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
```

```
 document.getElementById('audio').play();
```